# Good solution for picture slideshow performance wise

Tags: react-native

Has anyone ever implemented some sort of image slide show in React Native? I've currently been trying to implement React Native Swiper ( https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper ) and while it works, the performance switching picture to picture has a very choppy feel.

Is there any sort of solution for Picture Slideshows that other people have worked with. Ideally it would be dynamic so I could load in views upon loading the system

Any advice would be spectacular!

Right now here is my current implementation, it works.. but it isnt great. Figured this is pretty much irrelevant but decided to include it anyways just in case someone would want to see it

```
PictureFeed(){
var array = ["pic1","pic2","pic3","pic4"];

let Arr =array.map((a, i) => {

        return(
 <View key={i} style={styles.slide}>
        <Image source={{uri: {a}.a }} style={styles.image} />
        </View>
    );


    }) 


return(
  <Swiper style={styles.wrapper} showsButtons={true}>

{Arr}     

      </Swiper>

    );
}
```

Comment: React Native has its performance bottlenet due to the nature of RCT bridge. However, if you're testing your app on Android, be sure you've disabled debug mode, and not attached to any Android Studio debugging session, they both slowing down the animation significantly.

Comment: hmm okay, I was just running straight up debug mode off of my phone.. maybe thats it. I know react natives performance isn't going to be as nice as native but it just felt weird that a picture slideshow would be that choppy